# How to detect if systems and browser support adding Apple Passes to wallet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wallet, apple-wallet

I want to implement the ***Add to Apple Wallet*** button in my reactjs project to sync the passes with apple wallet. But there are restrictions like I can use the passes on *iPhone browser* and on *MacOS safari* only. While downloading on macOS safari It does download and open the pass, but on the other hand while attempting on *macOS Chrome* or Brave, it only downloads the file. So should I hide buttons in that case.

I have been through multiple documentation and blogs but I couldn't discover any combined and solid information on the devices and browsers that support adding passes to wallets and right approach to integrate the action on web and email.

There is a pre-default flag for Apple Pay Availability [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/apple_pay_js_api/checking_for_apple_pay_availability)
Looking for something similar flag or any package or any list which shows the supported configurations.

- How can I detect which user agent can support the downloading and opening the pass?
- What is the right approach to implement the "add to apple wallet" button in different situations like while using it on email templet and while rendering my button on for different browsers?

Comment: How did you manage to solve this?